# Windows 7 change password of another user without using "Set Password"

Tags: windows-7, passwords

I have a regular user account on my Windows 7 (Enterprise) machine, and an Administrator account for tasks requiring elevated privileges. I never actually log on as the admin user, I just use "Run as administrator" as this is on a Novell network and logging in as a local user is tricky with the current set-up we have (I'm not sure why, but it is).

I'd like to change the password for the administrator account, without resorting to the reset facility in Computer Management. When I use "Manage User Accounts" in control panel (with Run as administrator), it tells me that I need to press Ctrl-Alt-Del to change my own password, but obviously I can't do Ctrl-Alt-Del "as administrator."

Is there another way to change another user's password (given that you *do* know the current one) that doesn't involve logging in as that user or simply resetting it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First log into Administrator on command line:

```
runas /user: localmachinename \administrator cmd
```

Then change password with this command (edit it a little bit for your specific instance):

```
net user user_name  new_password
```

Comment: The Microsoft man pages don't give any detail on how to handle user names with a space.  I've tried `net user "A B" *`, `net user A B *`, `net user "domain\A B" *`, `net user "ab@domain" *`, and a half-dozen other combos.

Comment: I get: `System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied` :(

Comment: @IanGrainger Are you allowed to have administrator access?

Comment: @JosephHansen yes, I'm admin. I ran a CMD window as admin, but still got that error. Worried it's because I renamed the user? I've left the password for now, as the only problem is it's TOO long and copy/paste wasn't playing... So I guess I give in :)