# How to change my windows password automatically?

Tags: authentication, passwords, windows

I'm the only user of my laptop (running on Windows 7), (which makes me administrator). I want my system login password to keep changing automatically. For example, since today is Monday,  today's password should be "Monday" and tomorrow it should be changed to "Tuesday", and so on. How can I make this happen? Is there any application that allows me to do this? Or is there a script? Please let me know.

Comment: This isn't really a security-related question, but rather one about how to make a Windows system do something specific, which makes it a much better fit for [su] than [security.se]. I have voted for this to be migrated, so please don't repost this elsewhere in the network. That said, this sounds like a bad idea to me, but it's your system...

Comment: Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: @Spectrum You'll likely have to code your own Windows service to do this.  Which means you have a finite set of passwords.  You wouldn't be able to generate random passwords.  This would be more security through obscurity.  Changing your password every 90 days manually would be easier, and likely be more secure.

Comment: @RoraΖ It could be possible to use some derivation of a TOTP scheme for this, effectively generating an endless stream of unique passwords from a single secret. That being said, it still sounds like a bad idea. For instance, you're always one date change away from being locked out your machine.

Comment: @Specturm - What kind of attack are you envisioning that you feel changing your password automatically on a daily basis would thwart?

Comment: @RoraΖ It might allow him to tell certain people passwords... but that is about all I can imagine. @Spectrum?

Comment: It's not for security, I just thought it would be a fun idea that the password is changed automatically and only I know the pattern. I live in a hostel, so yeah, you get the picture. I got this idea from one of my friend whose iPhone unlock code was the time (hhmm) at that moment. Thanks for the suggestions though. especially @Stephane , I never considered that possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no in-built way to do this.

You could write a script to change a user's password in your favorite scripting language (batch, VBS, PowerShell, etc.), and then schedule it to run daily in Windows' Task Scheduler.

Here's some other SU questions to get you started with that:

- [Windows 7 change password of another user without using "Set Password"](https://superuser.com/questions/284762/windows-7-change-password-of-another-user-without-using-set-password)
- [PowerShell: create a new Active Directory user with password as a secure string](https://superuser.com/questions/740596/powershell-create-new-active-directory-user-with-password-as-secure-string)
- [Is there any way to change the Windows 7 password using the command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/456546/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-windows-7-password-using-the-command-prompt)

and a couple from StackOverflow:

- [WMI- Change User Password on remote computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552241/wmi-change-user-password-on-remote-computer)
- [PowerShell : change local Administrator password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532094/powershell-change-local-administrator-password)